# want to set category in phpbb3

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am new to `phpBB3`. I have just installed `phpBB3` on my `localhost`. I have gone through it. I am getting one problem that if I want to create two types of forum 
1. `Pre Sales` which can be seen by any visitor or `visitors who are logged in`
2. `Post Sales` which can be accessed by only the visitors who have paid for that 
please guys is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Pre sales` forum, you don't have to do anything special. Guests will be able to see that forum by default.

For `Post Sales`, you will create your forum, but do not copy permissions from any other forum when you do so. Then log into your Administrator Control Panel, select the `Forums` tab. On the left select `Forum Permissions`.

You have two options at this point. If you are placing users into groups, for example a `customer` group that can access `Post Sales`, you will use the `Groups` column. Otherwise, you'll be managing each individual user. I'm making the assumption that you will want to do this by group.

Select the group(s) you want to have access to this forum from the bottom right box. Click Add Permissions and they will appear in the upper right box. Now highlight all of them and select Edit Permissions.

From the next screen you can customize what they can('t) do on this specific forum. The easiest is to select one of the preconfigured options (Standard, Standard+Polls, etc), but if you want to can manage specific permissions as well.

Comment: if I had some post then how i will differentiate that this forum belongs to presales or postsales

Comment: I assume they are all in one forum right now, correct? In that case, you'd have to manually move the posts to the appropriate pre/post sales forum. Is this what you are asking?